# "CLI has stopped working" when trying to select all from an Oracle Database using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oracle

I am attempting to use JavaScript and Jquery to search a database. I have set up a generic query.php file so that I can pass in the database and query and have it return an array. For some reason, when I try to select all using the *, my PHP server crashes with:

[image]

I am using the built in server with PHP 7.0.2. I am attempting to retrieve information from a Oracle database.

Here is the post statement:

```
$.post(DB1.filename, 
        {sid: DB1.sid, 
        username: DB1.username, 
        password: DB1.password,
        host: DB1.host,
        port: DB1.port,
        sql: query}, 

        function(res){
            if(res == -1){
                res = errorCode(DATABASE_CONNECTION_ERROR);
            } else {
                var a = parseObject(res);
                var t = parseTable(a);
                elements[TABLE].element.innerHTML = t;
            }
            log(FILE_NAME, "RETRIEVED query ");
        }
    );
```

Here is the query.php:

```
<?php   
    /* This script will connect to a database and search the given SQL string.
        If the connection cannot be established, it will return -1. Otherwise, it will return a JSON array.
    */

    //Parameters
    $sql = $_POST["sql"];

    //Database Information
    $user = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $host = $_POST["host"];
    $port = $_POST["port"];
    $sid = $_POST["sid"];

    $connection = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " . $host .")(PORT = " . $port . ")) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = " . $sid . ")))";

    //Establish connection
    $conn = oci_connect($user, $pass, $connection);

    //Check connection
    if(!$conn){
        echo -1;
    } else {        
        //Query for the given SQL statement
        $stRows = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stRows);

        oci_fetch_all($stRows, $res); //This is where the everything actually crashes
        echo json_encode($res);

        //Close the connection
        oci_close($conn);
    } 
?>
```

So if I set the query as:

```
query = "select TABLE_NAME from ALL_TABLES";
```

everything works just fine. A table with a single column will be printed to the screen.

However, if I run:

```
query = "select * from ALL_TABLES";
```

I get the error above.

This happens regardless of which table I am attempting to connect to. My credentials are correct and I have tried different credentials as well. Any ideas why this is happening?

--UPDATE--

I tried hard coding the column names. I can select up to 8 columns before it crashes.There are 152 rows.

Comment: What does the php error log show?

Comment: maybe it is a memory limit problem. Try to set memory_limit to 0 in your php.

Comment: @steven - I tried this. It did not fix the issue...

Comment: @codeHeart - As I understand it, the built in PHP server does not have an error log by default. I added log_errors = On and error_log = /tmp/php_error.log to the php.ini file, but no log was created on crash.

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented the error by swapping the oci_fetch_all for oci_fetch_array as follows:

```
    <?php   

    ...

    } else {        
        //Query for the given SQL statement
        $stRows = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
        oci_execute($stRows);

        $res = array();
        while($row = oci_fetch_array($stRows, OCI_NUM)){
            $res[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($res);

        //Close the connection
        oci_close($conn);
    } 
?>
```

This meant drastic changes to the function used to decode the JSON object array, but it does work. I will not mark this answer as correct though because I would very much like to know why my original code wasn't working...